# Exportar dados da tela para excel

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Automatizei um teste de cadastro de clientes (realizado na Web, internet explorer) e ao final ele gera um protocolo e um outro código numérico.

Preciso que ao final da execução seja salvo estes dois dados, pois logo em seguida o sistema iniciara uma nova criação de cadastro.

Não sei fazer isso em Java, alguém pode me ajudar? Ja tentei com o Jsoup, porém não consegui.

Pode ser em excel, txt, de qualquer forma que seja simples a implementação, gravando no mesmo arquivo ou que a cada passagem ele gere um arquivo diferente com a informação da tela, não tem problema...só não posso perder estes dados ao final do processo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce pode usar o `Apache POI` para criar arquivos `xls`.

```
//Baixe o jar aqui "http://poi.apache.org/download.html"
    import  java.io.*;
    import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
    import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
    import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
    import  org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;

public class CreateExlFile{ // classe que gera o arquivo
     public static void main(String[]args){
         try{
            // local do arquivo
            String filename="C:/NewExcelFile.xls" ;
            HSSFWorkbook workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet =  workbook.createSheet("FirstSheet");  
            // criando as linhas
            HSSFRow rowhead=   sheet.createRow((short)0);
            rowhead.createCell(0).setCellValue("protocolo");
            rowhead.createCell(1).setCellValue("codigonumerico");
            // definindo seus valores
            // por exemplo protocolo.getProtocolo();
            HSSFRow row=   sheet.createRow((short)1);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(protocolo.getProtocolo());
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(protocolo.getCodigoNumerico());

            FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(filename);
            workbook.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Seu arquivo excel foi gerado!");

    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        System.out.println(ex);

    }
       }
   }
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas esta dando alguns erros, HSSFRow e HSSFWorkbook e HSSFSheet cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Baixou o arquivo JAR?????

Comment: Baixei sim e funcionou, depois de Eu apagar o código copiado e escrever manualmente, vai entender né rsrsrsrs De qualquer forma muito obrigado!